# Why can i get an EntityManagerFactory object from a LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean definition?

Tags: java, spring

I have the following bean definition in a file called *beans.xml*:

```
<bean id="entityManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="mypackagename" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass"
        value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And i can obtain this bean as an `EntityManagerFactory` object with the following code:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
EntityManagerFactory emf = context.getBean(EntityManagerFactory.class);
```

How is this possible?

As i see `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` does not implement `EntityManagerFactory`.

How does this work exactly?

Comment: `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` extends `AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean` which says *"Abstract FactoryBean that creates a local JPA `EntityManagerFactory` instance within a Spring application context. "*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain is as follows: `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean extends AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean` which implements `FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory>` and thus you're getting your `EntityManagerFactory`.

In fact you're requesting `EntityManagerFactory` from the `ApplicationContext` which already has `EntityManagerFactory` that created by appropriate `FactoryBean`.

Refer to [FactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: Ah i see, found it in the documentation of `FactoryBean`: A `FactoryBean` is defined in a bean style, but the object exposed for bean references (`getObject()`) is always the object that it creates. Thanks.